# Generics collection implementation java compilation error

Tags: java, generics, compilation

EDIT :

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    private class Node {
        protected Node next, prev;
        protected E data;

        protected Node(E dat) {
            data = dat;
            next = prev = null;
        }
    }

    private Node head, tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        (head = new Node(null)).next = tail = new Node(null);
        tail.prev = head;
        tail.next = head.prev = null;

    }

    public class LinkedListIterator {
        private Node current = null;

        public synchronized void resetToHead() {
            current = head.next;
        }

        public synchronized void resetToTail() {
            current = tail.prev;
        }

        public synchronized E get() {
            if (current!=null) return current.data;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that i get the following compilation Error on the emphasized lines :

```
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedList<E>.Node<E> to
> LinkedList<E>.Node<E>
```

what does it mean? and how do i fix this?

btw, the code is only part of the implementation so dont try to logicly figure it out.

Comment: didnt work, you may try that too, the code is compileable (other then the error i mentioned)

Comment: Don't make node a static inner class unless a `Node` should stand independently of a `LinkedList`.  Remove the generics parameter on the `Node` as it hides the outer generic type `E` in the LinkedList.

Comment: this isnt homework, im doing it as a part of my own project, to work with a more freindly to user linkedlist (i dont like Java's)

Comment: OK. I've removed the homework tag and my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

--- Edited as the question changes slightly ---

The question is now becoming, how do I have two inner classes coordinate generic types?  In short, they don't have to if they are both inner classes of an outer class where the generic type is bound.  So even with the `public synchronized E get()` in the non-generic `LinkedListIterator` you are returning an `E` (and it is type safe).

However, if you then reach out to implement `java.util.Iterator<E>` things fall apart, because that E is based on a different class (interface) so the `E` has different scoping.  How do you fix this?  You need to parameterize your `Node` classes to `Node<E>` to satisfy that `E` bindings exist on the implementation of `Iterator` even when that implementation is being used outside of the scope of it's originating class.  This forces `Node<E>` to be defined statically.

The reason it forces the static definition of `Node<E>` has to do with garbage collection.  An Iterator might still be holding references to `Node`s even though the `LinkedList` is scheduled for garbage collection.  Sure, you might be able to keep such a thing from happening with a specific implementation, but the JVM has to allow any implementation (even an errant one).

Perhaps it is easier to explain with code

```
  public LinkedList<E> {

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
      return new LinkedIterator(head);
    }

    // private because we don't want instances created outside of this LinkedList
    private class LinkedIterator implements Iterator<E> {

      // Right here, needing a parameterized next node will force Node to be static
      // static inner classes can exist outside of the scope of their parent
      // Since it can exist outside of the parent's scope, it needs it's own generic parameter
      private Node<E> next;

      LinkedIterator(Node start) {
        next = start;
      }

      public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
      }

      public E next() {
        Node<E> retValue = next;
        if (retValue != null) {
          next = retValue.next;
        }
        return retValue;
      }

    }

    // must be static because LinkedList might be garbage collected when
    // an Iterator still holds the node.
    // This E is not the same E as in LinkedList, because it is a E declaration (hiding the above E)
    private static Node<E> {
      Node<E> next;
      Node<E> prev;
      E data;
    }

  }
```

If you are not careful, you can now wind up back where you started; however, the key is to construct new `Node<E>` objects when needed in the parent scope.  Since that is the same scope where you construct LinkedIterator types, the generic type safety will be ensured.

--- Original post follows ----

By specifying that your node class definition is a `Node<E>`, you basically create a second, independently scoped generic type `E` which will hide the outer generic type `E` in the `LinkedList` class.

Since none of your classes are static, they will only exist within context of a LinkedList class, which will provide the generics binding.  That means you can simplify `Node<E>` to `Node` yet still put `E` class types within the `Node` class.  Same goes for the `LinkedListIterator`, except that if you want it to implement `Iterator` you should indicate it implements `Iterator<E>`.

Due to request, what follows is the code that compiles on my machine, (java 1.6.0_20)

```
public class LinkedList<E> {

    private class Node {
        protected Node next, prev;
        protected E data;

        protected Node(E dat) {
            data = dat;
            next = prev = null;
        }
    }

    private Node head, tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        (head = new Node(null)).next = tail = new Node(null);
        tail.prev = head;
        tail.next = head.prev = null;

    }

    public class LinkedListIterator {
        private Node current = null;
        public synchronized void resetToHead() {
            current = head.next;
        }

        public synchronized void resetToTail() {
            current = tail.prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked on my machine, in fact your posted code works on my machine too.

Comment: the problem is that if you create a new Iterator, you cant make it return E... and thats what i was aiming for...

Comment: Ok, the problem with iterator is actually slightly different.  I'll rewrite one more time.

Comment: thats better now, ill give it a closer look, will take a few minutes.

Comment: LinkedListIterator was suppose to be an extension to Iterator and was meant to have more options like moveToNext() and moveToPrev() (i meant to implement a real linkedlist functionality) , with your changes, i have to use Iterator, which i was trying to avoid and is the reason why i went implementing my own LinkedList rather then using java's...

Comment: @OfekRon You don't have to use my extensions.  You can do whatever you please.  I just showed you how to do it, not dictated which way you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

You overdid it a bit by parametrising the embedded classes. I removed all unnecessary ones.

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    private class Node {
        protected Node next, prev;
        protected E data;

        protected Node(E dat) {
            data = dat;
            next = prev = null;
        }
    }

    private Node head, tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        (head = new Node(null)).next = tail = new Node(null);
        tail.prev = head;
        tail.next = head.prev = null;

    }

    public class LinkedListIterator {
        private Node current = null;

        public synchronized void resetToHead() {
        current = head.next;
        }

        public synchronized void resetToTail() {
            current = tail.prev;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively with a *static* class Node.

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    private static class Node<E2> {
        protected Node next, prev;
        protected E2 data;

        protected Node(E2 dat) {
            data = dat;
            next = prev = null;
        }
    }

    private Node<E> head, tail;

    public LinkedList() {
        (head = new Node(null)).next = tail = new Node(null);
        tail.prev = head;
        tail.next = head.prev = null;

    }

    public class LinkedListIterator {
        private Node<E> current = null;

        public synchronized void resetToHead() {
            current = head.next;
        }

        public synchronized void resetToTail() {
            current = tail.prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't understand that the <E> in LinkedListIterator is the same <E> as the parent class.  Just remove  from the inner class:

```
    public class LinkedListIterator {
        private Node<E> current = null;

        public synchronized void resetToHead() {
            current = head.next;
        }

        public synchronized void resetToTail() {
            current = tail.prev;
        }
    }
```